# How to style echoed text?

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to style the user, time and content. they only appear once the user has entered a comment into the website and so I cannot use `<p>` tags with inline CSS. any suggestions?

```
if ($result->num_rows != 0 )
{
    $row;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo("</br>");
        echo("User: ".$row['user']."</br>");
        echo("Time: ".$row['time']."</br>");
        echo("Message: ".$row['content']."</br>");


    }
} 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- create a class in your css (i.e: myClass)

2- use echo like this:
echo `'User: <span class="myClass">'.$row['user'].'</span></br>'` ;

**Edited**:

html characters in php are like string!
so you may concat them all like this:

```
echo '</br> 
      <div class="myClass">
        User: '.$row['user']
        .'</br> 
        Time: '.$row['time']
        .'</br>
        Message: '.$row['content']
      .'</div> </br>';
```

Comment: is there any way that i could group all three together to perhaps give them all a background

Comment: you can concat them all via dot (.), they are like strings. I edited the answer